# How to open psql prompt for PostgreSQL in FreeBSD?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, freebsd

I have installed PostgreSQL on my FreeBSD 8.2 box. How can I open the SQL prompt so I can write SQL queries?

I can do:

```
su pgsql
```

Which opens a prompt but I cannot write SQL queries like SELECT or CREATE there. Sorry, I am new to PostgreSQL.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Python or django?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use django's management command `python manage.py dbshell` to open the database-specific connection (same across dev / production).

It does other useful things like specifying the database and username listed in `settings.py`

Otherwise I'd have to type in something like `psql db_name -U user`

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to connect to an existing database first, before making queries, on PostgreSQL?
(BTW are you sure it's `pgsql` the command you want, not `psql`?)

If that's really your problem, you can connect to an existing database either when you open the shell:

```
psql mydatabase
```

Or after using the `\c` command:

```
psql
myuser=> \c mydatabase
```